# org.mockito.exceptions.verification.WantedButNotInvoked:

Tags: java

```
Mockito.when(
                useCaseService.
                addPurposeForModelDeployment(
                Mockito.any(UseCase.class)))
        .thenReturn(registrationDetailsForModelData);

        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(post(URI)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(inputInJson)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andReturn();

        MockHttpServletResponse response = result.getResponse();

        String outputInJson = response.getContentAsString();
        logger.info("response="+outputInJson);

        assertThat(outputInJson).isNotEqualTo(inputInJson);
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK.value(), response.getStatus());
        Mockito.verify(useCaseService).addPurposeForModelDeployment(registrationDetailsForModelData);
```

Comment: Your method is not invoked, what is not clear about that?

Comment: Please describe your question.

Answer (score 0):

WantedButNotInvoked Exception is thrown when method call is not verified . please make sure that useCaseService.addPurposeForModelDeployment() is being invoked by the test Method.